# Scripting capabilities in the Registry section

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

Our software supports a range (~70) of file associations that a user can select to associate with our application.
It is straight forward to set this up in the `Registry` section of the installer and use flags to control behavior during uninstalling as well as the `Check` flag to control if it should be written to the registry or not.
The users can control which associations to setup via a custom page with a `CheckListBox`.

What I'm wondering now is if there is a method to loop over the `CheckBox` items of the `CheckListBox` inside the `Registry` section? Currently I can only imagine that I would have to create all the registry entries via the `Code` section but that would require me to also write the code for the uninstaller as the flags controlling the uninstall behavior are not available here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use Pascal code to generate `Registry` section entries.

But you can use [Inno Setup preprocessor](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/) to generate both your `Registry` sections as well as the code for adding the extensions to the `CheckListBox`. Something like this:

```
#define Extension(Mode, Ext) \
  Mode == "Registry" ? \
    "Root: HKCU; Subkey: ""Software\My Company""; ValueType: string; ValueName: """ + \
      Ext + """; ValueData: ""yes""; Check: RegisterExtension('" + Ext + "')" + NewLine \
  : Mode == "Check" ? \
    "  if (Ext = '" + Ext + "') and CheckListBox.Checked[I] then Exit;" + NewLine + \
    "  Inc(I); " + NewLine \
  : Mode == "AddCheckbox" ? \
    "  CheckListBox.AddCheckBox('" + Ext + "', '', 0, True, True, False, True, nil);" + \
      NewLine \
  : ""


#define Extensions(Mode) \
  Extension(Mode, 'jpg') + \
  Extension(Mode, 'gif') + \
  Extension(Mode, 'png') + \
  ""
```

```
[Registry]
#emit Extensions("Registry")
```

```pascal
[Code]

var
  CheckListBox: TNewCheckListBox;

function RegisterExtension(Ext: string): Boolean;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  I := 0;
  Result := True;
  #emit Extensions("Check")
  Result := False;
end;

procedure AddExtensionsToCheckListBox;
begin
  #emit Extensions("AddCheckbox")
end;
```

- `Registry` entry is just a (useless) example.
- Call `AddExtensionsToCheckListBox` somewhere from the code, where you are creating the `CheckListBox`.

*See my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60460082/850848#60502833) for a less elegant, but more readable solution.*

---

To see what this does, add this to the end of your script:

```
#expr SaveToFile(AddBackslash(SourcePath) + "Preprocessed.iss")
```

Check the the `Preprocessed.iss` after compilation. It should give you something like *(empty lines and line wrapping added for readability)*:

```pascal
[Registry]
Root: HKCU; Subkey: "Software\My Company"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "jpg"; \
  ValueData: "yes"; Check: RegisterExtension('jpg')
Root: HKCU; Subkey: "Software\My Company"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "gif"; \
  ValueData: "yes"; Check: RegisterExtension('gif')
Root: HKCU; Subkey: "Software\My Company"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "png"; \
  ValueData: "yes"; Check: RegisterExtension('png')

[Code]
var
  CheckListBox: TNewCheckListBox;

function RegisterExtension(Ext: string): Boolean;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  I := 0;
  Result := True;
  if (Ext = 'jpg') and CheckListBox.Checked[I] then Exit;
  Inc(I); 
  if (Ext = 'gif') and CheckListBox.Checked[I] then Exit;
  Inc(I); 
  if (Ext = 'png') and CheckListBox.Checked[I] then Exit;
  Inc(I); 
  Result := False;
end;

procedure AddExtensionsToCheckListBox;
begin
  CheckListBox.AddCheckBox('jpg', '', 0, True, True, False, True, nil);
  CheckListBox.AddCheckBox('gif', '', 0, True, True, False, True, nil);
  CheckListBox.AddCheckBox('png', '', 0, True, True, False, True, nil);
end;
```

---

For somewhat different approach that makes use of [event attributes](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=eventattributes) that were not available, at the time I wrote this answer:
[Array Variables and dynamic access in [Code] section](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73337820/850848)

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what i was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

I've came up with an alternative solution to my [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60460082/850848#60463260). It is less elegant. But probably a way more readable, particularly to someone not experienced with Inno Setup preprocessor syntax.

It uses the preprocessor [`#sub` directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=sub), which allows using native Inno Setup syntax to generate the `Registry` section, instead of constructing it using a preprocessor expression. The preprocessor code generates a poll of indexed entries, which are conditionally used on runtime. You just need to make sure that `MaxExt` is large enough to fit all your extensions.

*I didn't test it, so there might be minor bugs. But the concept will work.*

```
#define MaxExt 100

[Registry]
#define I

#sub RegistryEntry
Root: HKCU; Subkey: "Software\My Company"; ValueType: string; \
  ValueName: "{code:GetExt|{#I}}"; ValueData: "yes"; Check: RegisterExt({#I})
#endsub

#for {I = 0; I < MaxExt; I++} RegistryEntry
```

```pascal
[Code]

var
  Exts: TStrings;
  CheckListBox: TNewCheckListBox;

function RegisterExt(I: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  Result := (I < CheckListBox.Items.Count) and CheckListBox.Checked[I];
end;

function GetExt(Param: string): string;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  I := StrToInt(Param);
  if I < Exts.Count then Result := Exts[I]
    else Result := 'unused';
end;

procedure AddExt(Ext: string);
begin
  { Separate list of extensions is needed only in case that the list box items caption }
  { is more complex than a mere extension name. Otherwise you could read the extension }
  { name from checked item caption in GetExt. }
  Exts.Add(Ext);
  CheckListBox.AddCheckBox(Ext, '', 0, True, True, False, True, nil);
end;

procedure AddExtensionsToCheckListBox;
begin
  Exts := TStringList.Create;
  AddExt('jpg');
  AddExt('gif');
  AddExt('png');
  { ... }
end;
```

- `Registry` entry is just a (useless) example.
- Call `AddExtensionsToCheckListBox` somewhere from the code, where you are creating the `CheckListBox`.

---

To see what the preprocesor part does, add this to the end of your script:

```
#expr SaveToFile(AddBackslash(SourcePath) + "Preprocessed.iss")
```

Check the the `Preprocessed.iss` after compilation. It should contain lie of 100 generated entries like this:

```
[Registry]
Root: HKCU; Subkey: "Software\My Company"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "{code:GetExt|0}"; ValueData: "yes"; Check: RegisterExt(0)
Root: HKCU; Subkey: "Software\My Company"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "{code:GetExt|1}"; ValueData: "yes"; Check: RegisterExt(1)
Root: HKCU; Subkey: "Software\My Company"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "{code:GetExt|2}"; ValueData: "yes"; Check: RegisterExt(2)
...
Root: HKCU; Subkey: "Software\My Company"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "{code:GetExt|99}"; ValueData: "yes"; Check: RegisterExt(99)
```

Comment: After a bit of trial and error to get the double quotes right in your initial, I got it all to work and added the option to also have groups in the CheckListBox. Writing the long expressions is a bit cumbersome when looking for errors but I'm very happy with your first solution.