# Evaluate a collection of data from preprocessor on run time in Inno Setup Pascal Script

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I am trying to get Inno Setup define value in `Code` section but not with `{#VersionTool1}`. I need to pass defined name dynamically, because there are a lot of them (I want to avoid large switch case). I tried `SetupSetting` but it's not in Setup section (it's before it). Is there any way to do this?

```pascal
#define VersionTool1 2019.01.1111
#define VersionTool2 2020.02.2111

...

[Code]

procedure SetSelectedTool(ToolName: String);
var
  CurrentTool: string;
begin
  ...
  CurrentTool := 'Version' + ToolName;
  CurrentToolVersion := {#CurrentTool};
  ...
end;
```

Value of local variable `CurrentTool` wil for example be `'VersionTool1'` and I want to get value of `VersionTool1` preprocessor variable which is `2020.02.2111`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible, see [Evaluate preprocessor macro on run time in Inno Setup Pascal Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41070563/850848).

---

But there are other solutions.

For example:

```pascal
[Code]
var
  ToolNames: TStringList;
  ToolVersions: TStringList;

function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
begin
  ToolNames := TStringList.Create;
  ToolVersions := TStringList.Create;

  #define AddToolVersion(Name, Version) \
    "ToolNames.Add('" + Name + "'); ToolVersions.Add('" + Version +"');"

  #emit AddToolVersion('Tool1', '2019.01.1111')
  #emit AddToolVersion('Tool2', '2020.02.2111')
  // ...

  Result := True;
end;
```

*(of course, the above makes sense only if you actually do not hardcode the version numbers, but use a code that only a preprocessor can do – something like `GetStringFileInfo`, what I've understood from your comments that you plan to)*

---

And then you can have a function like:

```pascal
function GetToolVersion(ToolName: string): string;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  I := ToolNames.IndexOf(ToolName);
  if I >= 0 then Result := ToolVersions[I];
end;
```

---

Another similar questions:

- [Array variables and dynamic access in [Code] section](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73337820/850848)
- [Scripting capabilities in the Registry section](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60460082/850848)